# How to get configured firmware keyboard layout in UEFI?

Tags: c, uefi, edk2

We can configure keyboard layout language in firmware settings. See the screenshot below

[image]

How can I get string name of this configured firmware keyboard layout in UEFI in form like "**en_US**" or "**de_DE**"?

I can use efilib or EDK-2

Comment: I doubt you can get a name like that (e.g. how would you tell the difference between "US Dvorak" and "US Qwerty" when they're both "`en_US`"?). There is a `EFI_HII_DATABASE_PROTOCOL.GetKeyboardLayout()` function, but it's a little messy (it gives you the address of a structure and the offset of a description string in that structure) and I have no idea what the description strings look like.